# Need to solve a “pseudo-metabolic” network for rates

Tags: r, optimization, networks

Sorry about the re-post from Biology section...
following problem:

I have data on a certain complex association network (from monomers 1 ... 8 to complexes of all combinations, such as, 12 ... 13 ... 18 and so on until 12345678, so that I know

the structure of the network (255 vertices)
the edges of the network
the concentrations of the vertices
From this data I now wish to infer the preferred route(s) of assembly for those complexes - which should be the rate constants for the edges, such as 1 --> 12 or 145 --> 1458. Does that make sense?
Final result should be a set of paths of length 8 starting from (1..8) ending up at (12345678).

I have now tried various standalone applications for network creation/analysis as well as R packages. Metabolic flux analysis seemed promising for me, but it turned out that it only works with set external concentrations and assumes steady-state for all metabolites within the network. Which is not the case for me. Do you know of any alternative method?

Comment: Why not post this question to SOCNET@LISTS.UFL.EDU? It's a listserv for network-related questions...